# htaccess remove index.php and index.php/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla

I've google a lot but I can't find any rule to remove the index.php from both cases:

1. domain.com/index.php  => domain.com
2. domain.com/index.php/other/stuff => domain.com/other/stuff

Here is what I've done so far

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(administrator) [NC] #exclude administrator folder
#RewriteRule ^index.php$ /$1 [R=301] #when this is enable work only first case
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] #when this is enable work only second case
```

If I enable both cases all requests are redirected to domain.com

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure that MOD rewrite is ON .

try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

hope this works !

Comment: PHP 5.3.28 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Oct 25 2014 13:49:56)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com v5.0.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by ionCube Ltd.

Comment: try this .. 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: did you rename the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

hope this works !

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|assets|robots\
.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```